# Batteries have a constant charging speed from 0%→70% instead of being any faster at 0%?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charging, mobile, mobile-phones

A mobile phone I tested keeps charging **at the same constant speed from 0% to 70%,** which is 10 watts. It uses MediaTek PumpExpress (input power: 12V 0.83A, despite the wall charger is capable of 12V 1.5A).

Why does it not charge at e.g. **15 watts when at 0%?**

Another phone charges at 9V 1.67A (15W) using Qualcomm fast charging. It maintains **the exact same charging speed from 0% to 60%**. I wonder, why it does not charge **any faster while being at indicated 0%** than while being at 60%.

Side note: I actually keep my batteries in the healthy percentage range.

Comment: Look at how a Li-Ion charger works : Constant Current, then Constant Voltage, then cutoff. Roughly 70% is the Constant Current phase - and a constant rate of increase of charge is the very definition of constant current.

Comment: Why do you think it should be faster at 0%?

Comment: Mobiles are responsible for their own battery choices and charge rates. Not the charger

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I just meant, that the charger **offers a higher speed,** which the mobile phone could make use of if it wanted to.

Comment: @pjc50 Because the battery is emptier at 0% than at 60%, so it should be charging faster at 0% than at 60%.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Constant current, yes. So do you mean it is normal for a battery to have the exact same charging speed at 5% capacity as at 60%?

Comment: As Bimpelrekkie says, no it should really charge slower below 30% and speed up where the battery is healthiest. But its a phone and its not designed with long life as a top priority.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's why some mobile phones have **user-replaceable** batteries.

Comment: It’s the classic compromise between impatient users in a rush tradeoff with lifespan

Comment: How are you measuring the charge rate? The user-facing battery display may not be linear.

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining the exact same charging speed from 0% to 60% batterlevel is in my opinion a **bad design choice**. Yes it charges your battery faster but it also **puts more stress on it**. At least these phone slow down the charging above 60% to 70 % and that's a must.

It is generally recommended to only fast-charge Lithium based batteries (practically all phone batteries are Lithium based) at a charge level between 30% to 70 % (maybe 20 % to 80 % is ok-ish as well).

When a Lithium based battery is below 30% or above 70 % charge level fast-charging puts extra stress on the battery and this causes wear. So do that often and the battery will wear out sooner.

So a properly designed phone will only charge at maximum speed when the battery is not at a too low level and not almost full. If a phone does not do that then it is not treating the battery for optimal lifetime.

Source: [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/) and others.

Comment: Only fast charge 30% to 70%? Not 0% to 70%?

Comment: So you mean that instead of the charging speed being higher at 0%, it should be lower at 60%, and the initial charging speed at 0% capacity is already the maximum recommended speed?

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries indicates that recommended method is to fast charge from 0%.  However, overdischarged cells may recover if trickle charged to 2.5-3V, after which they can accept full charging current.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Where did you read that? I do not see fast charging for Lithium based cells mentioned. What you might have readt is that they mean that **normal charging** (so at 1C, that's not fast charging) can start from 0% once the voltage has recovered enough. And again, I'm not saying (fast) charging cannot be done or should not be done at 0% charge level. It just stresses the battery more when you do.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, I was using "fast charge" to indicate the current limiting phase of a normal charge cycle.  I wouldn't recommend charging over 1C at any point in the charge cycle without detailed communication with the battery manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

Constant charging speed from "conditional 0" to 60% is a simple matter of basic 
standard Li-Ion charging method - the charger is in CC - constant current mode. See [more details here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388234/117785).